# Laravel switched servers to aws now pages are expiring

Tags: laravel

I switched a project from a small server company to aws that was running laravel 5.5 and when I login it goes to a page expired right away. Any idea of why this would happen?

Comment: Is there any load balancing happening on the AWS side? What session driver are you using?

Comment: Yes and I feel a little foolish but I figured it out after stepping away for a bit. This was my first aws set up from scratch. I didn’t know you needed to turn on sessions by default. I turned them on and it worked. Leaving this here in case anyone does this in the future.